# Future inside future always pending

Tags: python, python-asyncio, faust

P.S. Started an issue https://github.com/robinhood/faust/issues/702

Developing [Faust](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)-app:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

import faust

app = faust.App('my-app-name', broker='kafka://localhost:9092')
sink = app.topic('topic')


@app.task()
async def check():
    # 3 is amount of different folders where archives are laced
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        fs = [executor.submit(handle, directory) for directory in ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']]
        for future in as_completed(fs):
            future.result()


def handle(directory):
    # finding archives in directory
    # unpacking 7z with mdb-files
    # converting mdb tables to csv
    # reading csv to dataframe
    # some data manipulating
    # and at last sending dataframe records to kafka
    f = sink.send_soon(value={'ts': 1234567890, 'count': 10})  # always in pending status
```

Faced a problem when method **[sink.send_soon](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/faust.topics.html?highlight=send_soon#faust.topics.Topic.send_soon)** returns *FutureMessage(asyncio.Future, Awaitable[RecordMetadata])* which is always in pending status.

This is the situation when future inside another future.

Note. Function **handle** should be sync because one cannot pass async function to ProcessPollExecutor. Method **send_soon** is sync method. According to this example https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/b5e159f1d104ad4a6aa674d14b6ba0be19b5f9f5/examples/windowed_aggregation.py#L47 awaiting is not necessarily.

If there any way to handle pending future?

Also tried this:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import faust

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

app = faust.App('my-app-name', broker='kafka://localhost:9092', loop=loop)
sink = app.topic('topic')


@app.task()
async def check():
    tasks = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for dir_ in ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']:
            task = asyncio.create_task(run_dir_handling(executor, dir_))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def run_dir_handling(executor, dir_):
    print('running blocking')
    await loop.run_in_executor(executor, handle, dir_)


def handle(directory):
    print('Handle directory')

    # finding archives in directory
    # unpacking 7z with mdb-files
    # converting mdb tables to csv
    # reading csv to dataframe
    # some data manipulating
    # and at last sending dataframe records to kafka

    # `send_soon` is not non-`async def but `send` is async
    # async `soon` cannot be implemented because of
    #    `await loop.run_in_executor(executor, handle, dir_) TypeError: cannot pickle 'coroutine' object` error
    f = sink.send_soon(value={'ts': 1234567890, 'count': 10, 'dir': directory})
    print(f)  # always <FutureMessage pending>
```

But it didn't work too.

It seems loop is not even have a chance to run send_soon method.

Comment: Did you try _awaiting_ `sink.send_soon(...)`? If it's an async function, it must be awaited.

Comment: It is not async function

Comment: But it returna a future or a future-like object, which you might need to await anyway. Or you should at least run the event loop long enough for your tasks to process.

Comment: I understand your misunderstanding. According to this example https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/b5e159f1d104ad4a6aa674d14b6ba0be19b5f9f5/examples/windowed_aggregation.py#L47 it is not necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed code structure for this:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import faust

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

app = faust.App('my-app-name', broker='kafka://localhost:9092')
sink = app.topic('topic1')


@app.task()
async def check():
    tasks = []

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for dir_ in ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']:
            task = asyncio.create_task(run_dir_handling(executor, dir_))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def run_dir_handling(executor, dir_):
    directory = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, handle, dir_)
    await sink.send(value={'dir': directory})  
    

def handle(directory):
    print('Handle directory')

    # finding archives in directory
    # unpacking 7z with mdb-files
    # converting mdb tables to csv
    # reading csv to dataframe
    # some data manipulating
    # and at last sending dataframe records to kafka

    return directory
```